# Apache mod_rewrite help?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite requests like:

```
mydomain.com/this/is/a/test
```

to:

```
mydomain.com/url.php?i=this,is,a,test
```

How can I write a rule that can handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a .htaccess file with the below contents and place it in your root web directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +Followsymlinks

RewriteRule (.*) url.php?i=$1
```

That would create a query string of `this/is/a/test` instead of your requested comma-separated value; that's nothing a quick string-replace function (like `str_replace()` in PHP) couldn't fix.